# TypeError: cannot serialize '_io.BufferedRandom' object While trying to upload file in Django

Tags: django

I am trying to upload some files in Django but sometimes when the file size increases it gives the following error:

> TypeError: cannot serialize '_io.BufferedRandom' object

In the current case I am trying to upload a file(size ~3Mb) but it's still showing the error.
I tried to check in the network that if the file has been uploaded or not but it shows:

[image]

I am unable to understand what changes I need to make in order to resolve this

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try setting `FILE_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE = 5242880` in `settings.py` to a higher value (5MB) so that files (<5MB) become `InMemoryUploadedFile`.

> Default: 2621440 (i.e. 2.5 MB).
>
> The maximum size (in bytes) that an upload will be before it gets
> streamed to the file system.

See [**Uploaded Files and Upload Handlers**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/files/uploads/#module-django.core.files.uploadedfile).

In the [**class MemoryFileUploadHandler(FileUploadHandler)**](https://github.com/django/django/blob/11c4a4412b74bb1dfe52d706a58f230066821c33/django/core/files/uploadhandler.py#L172) it checks for the content length and if it's greater then it's use `TemporaryFileUploadHandler`:

```
def handle_raw_input(self, input_data, META, content_length, boundary, encoding=None):
    """
    Use the content_length to signal whether or not this handler should be
    used.
    """
    # Check the content-length header to see if we should
    # If the post is too large, we cannot use the Memory handler.
    self.activated = content_length <= settings.FILE_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE
```